# Is it advisable to continue building links while attempting to remove a penalty?

Tags: keywords, penalty, link-building

I have a penalty removal I need to begin working on on one of my sites. It was a manual action for unnatural links around a keyword that's particularly valuable to my site.

My question is, is it a bad idea to continue building (100% bettter!) links for that keyword while I'm also going through the process of identifying and disavowing the unnatural links? I ask because if I don't do this, I'll lose at least 2 months to this process and it will take me even longer to recover rankings for that keyword...

Comment: `links for that keyword` that's your biggest mistake... nothing is more unnatural than keyword anchor texts for selective keywords, your get your site slapped silly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're manually building backlinks, you should at least make them look natural. Remember, when people are linking to things on the web, they rarely care about the keywords or the key phrases that are being used in the anchor text. For example, say I have a page called `http://example.com/hotel-reviews` and that people are naturally linking to it. The anchor text will be varied. Examples include:

1. `here`, `click here` and `this`.
2. Raw links to the page: `http://example.com/hotel-reviews` i.e. No anchor text. This is extremely common.
3. The domain name will sometimes be used: `Example.com`
4. `This review`
5. `A number of other reviewers have also noticed` etc, etc.
6. `Read More`

Basically, if the majority of your links use the exact same keyword-focused anchor text, Google is going to know that that something is amiss.

Personally, I think that you are playing with fire here as it is obvious that you are making it obvious.

Comment: I would add that many links made organically by users are somewhat conversational. The tactic when creating backlinks is to be conversational and use a plethora of related terms. One piece of advice I can give is this- *STOP(!)* thinking in terms of keyword manipulations. This went out with the dodo bird quite some time ago.